# ERROR: The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'

Tags: flutter

```
tabs: [
                  GButton(
                    **icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/home.png')),**
                    text: 'Home',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    **icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/consultation.png')),**
                    text: 'Previous Consultations',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    **icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/menu.png')),**
                    text: 'Menu',
                  ),
                ],
```

Comment: Can you include more about `GButton`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `ImageIcon` in `IconData`.

Reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html

You can use `leading` instead,

```
GButton(
    icon: LineIcons.user,
    text: 'Now',
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 10,
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          ''),
        ),
      )
```

Or use `IconButton`,

```
new IconButton(
    icon: ImageIcon(NetworkImage("Image"), color: Colors.white),
    onPressed: () async {},
  )
```